# Chrome on Windows 8. Everytime I close it and then reopen it says the browsers was not properly closed

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

Chrome, the metro app, on Windows 8 always says to me that the browser was not properly closed everytime I restart it. This happens also whenever I turn on the PC and start Chrome.  How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I'm assuming this is the Metro Version, and not the desktop, as I've noticed this as well.

Comment: This isn't happening for me.  Have you made sure that Chrome is up to date?  You can also try assigning Internet Explorer to be the default browser, then changing it back to Chrome.

Comment: I just noticed I don't know how to assign IE as the main browser in Win8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has a few glitches when used in Metro. I have similar problems with Chrome in Metro. To solve this problem, Try to avoid using Metro, instead use the desktop version of Chrome. As for links that default to Metro, try deleting the Metro app link

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I used Alt-F4 and it actually worked. The next time I opened chrome it went straight into the page I wanted it to open into, which was google.com, and it didn't have the "Google chrome didn't shut down properly" thing. Hope this works for you.